# Filebeat load balancing - algorithm

Tags: filebeat

I have configured the filebeat to send logs to logsstash.

In my environment I have filebeat pointing to the 3 hosts where logstash is configured.

in the filebeat configuration file you can enable load balancing:

[filebeat loadbalancing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/load-balancing.html)

question_1:
I need to know, if enable load balancing on filebeat config which algorithm will use (for instance, round robin)?

question_2:
in the current configuration with 3 hosts under the output.logstash section in filebeat, how  it will send the logs(I mean all in the 1rst server & in case of failure to the second one)?

Thank you all.